# Can't find a way to scrape the resultant table after search using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I've been doing webscrape with BeautifulSoup, Selenium and Scrapy for a few months, mainly for research purposes. After up and downs I always managed to achieve my web-scraping objectives (a lot of them thanks to this site) until I face this site 'https://euclid.eba.europa.eu/register/cir/search' the page uses javascript and needs to be rendered in order to get the results. With selenium, I managed to click on Continue, Select EEA-Brach type and click on search but after getting the page source code of the results I only get script code and not the rendered html/css as usual. Is there a way to scrape this site?

```
driver.get('https://euclid.eba.europa.eu/register/cir/search')
sleep(1)
movetostring = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-cir/div[1]/div/app-disclaimer-page/div/div[3]/p")
action.move_to_element(movetostring).perform()  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-cir/div[1]/div/app-disclaimer-page/div/p-button/button/span[1]").click()
sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p-card/div/div/div/p-card[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/p-dropdown/div/label').click()
sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(/html/body/app-root/app-cir/div[1]/div/app-app-entity-search/form/p-card/div/div/div/p-card[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/p-dropdown/div/div[4]/div/ul/li[1]).click()
sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-cir/div[1]/div/app-app-entity-search/form/p-card/div/div/div/p-card[2]/div/div/div/p-button[1]/button').click()
sleep(2)
html=driver.page_source
```

Comment: Is it possible that the site didn't fully load? Try adding a time.out

Comment: Thank you @MLAlex that was the issue, the site has some inestable wait times, DebajanB's response solved my issue better than expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the *page source* of the *resultant table* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  driver.get("https://euclid.eba.europa.eu/register/cir/search")
  driver.execute_script("scroll(0, 250)")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.ui-button-text.ui-clickable"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@class='ng-tns-c9-4 ui-dropdown-label ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-placeholder ng-star-inserted' and contains(., 'Please select')]"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='ui-dropdown-items ui-dropdown-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset']//li//span[text()='EEA Branch']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ui-button-text ui-clickable' and text()='Search']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tbody.ui-table-tbody tr")))
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tbody.ui-table-tbody"))).get_attribute("outerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <tbody class="ui-table-tbody"><!----><!----><!----><!----><tr _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="ng-star-inserted"><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; vertical-align: top;"> EEA Branch</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10em; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/BE_1500"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted">BPCE Lease, Sucursal en Espana</span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/BE_1500"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted">BPCE Lease, Sucursal en España</span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;">BE_1500</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;"><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="flag-icon flag-icon-es"></span><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="">ES</span></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;">Madrid</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width: 4em;"><p-button _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" icon="pi pi-eye" ptooltip="View" tooltipposition="left" tabindex="0"><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" style=""><!----><span class="pi pi-eye ui-clickable ui-button-icon-left ng-star-inserted"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">ui-btn</span></button></p-button></td></tr><!----><!----><tr _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="ng-star-inserted"><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; vertical-align: top;"> EEA Branch</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10em; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/F0HUI1NY1AZMJMD8LP67FR"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted">HSBC France Bank, Stockholm Filial</span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/F0HUI1NY1AZMJMD8LP67FR"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;">516406-1169</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;"><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="flag-icon flag-icon-se"></span><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="">SE</span></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;">Stockholm</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width: 4em;"><p-button _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" icon="pi pi-eye" ptooltip="View" tooltipposition="left" tabindex="0"><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" style=""><!----><span class="pi pi-eye ui-clickable ui-button-icon-left ng-star-inserted"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">ui-btn</span></button></p-button></td></tr><!----><!----><tr _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="ng-star-inserted"><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; vertical-align: top;"> EEA Branch</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10em; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/ROROPJS40074"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted">BNP Paribas Personal Finance S.A. Paris Sucursala Bucuresti </span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/ROROPJS40074"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;">RB-PJS-40-074</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;"><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="flag-icon flag-icon-ro"></span><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="">RO</span></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;">Bucuresti</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;">Bucuresti</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width: 4em;"><p-button _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" icon="pi pi-eye" ptooltip="View" tooltipposition="left" tabindex="0"><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" style=""><!----><span class="pi pi-eye ui-clickable ui-button-icon-left ng-star-inserted"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">ui-btn</span></button></p-button></td></tr><!----><!----><tr _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="ng-star-inserted"><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; vertical-align: top;"> EEA Branch</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10em; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/BE_0131"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted">NOVO BANCO, S.A., SUCURSAL EN ESPANA</span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/BE_0131"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;">BE_0131</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;"><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="flag-icon flag-icon-es"></span><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="">ES</span></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;">MADRID</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width: 4em;"><p-button _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" icon="pi pi-eye" ptooltip="View" tooltipposition="left" tabindex="0"><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" style=""><!----><span class="pi pi-eye ui-clickable ui-button-icon-left ng-star-inserted"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">ui-btn</span></button></p-button></td></tr><!----><!----><tr _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="ng-star-inserted"><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; vertical-align: top;"> EEA Branch</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10em; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;">969500QQVZTWFHPN2O17</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/969500QQVZTWFHPN2O17"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted">Hoist finance AB</span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/969500QQVZTWFHPN2O17"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;">23033</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;"><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr"></span><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="">FR</span></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;">LA MADELEINE </td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width: 4em;"><p-button _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" icon="pi pi-eye" ptooltip="View" tooltipposition="left" tabindex="0"><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" style=""><!----><span class="pi pi-eye ui-clickable ui-button-icon-left ng-star-inserted"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">ui-btn</span></button></p-button></td></tr><!----><!----><tr _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="ng-star-inserted"><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; vertical-align: top;"> EEA Branch</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10em; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/FI20085_VAR_GEN_MIG"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted">J.P. Morgan Europe Limited, Helsingin sivuliike</span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/FI20085_VAR_GEN_MIG"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;">22047862</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;"><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="flag-icon flag-icon-fi"></span><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="">FI</span></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;">HELSINKI</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width: 4em;"><p-button _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" icon="pi pi-eye" ptooltip="View" tooltipposition="left" tabindex="0"><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" style=""><!----><span class="pi pi-eye ui-clickable ui-button-icon-left ng-star-inserted"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">ui-btn</span></button></p-button></td></tr><!----><!----><tr _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="ng-star-inserted"><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; vertical-align: top;"> EEA Branch</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10em; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/FI8907V_VAR_GEN_MIG"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted">Credit Agricole Corporate and Investment Bank Helsingin sivukonttori</span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/FI8907V_VAR_GEN_MIG"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted">Crédit Agricole Corporate and Investment Bank Helsingin sivukonttori</span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;">09003611</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;"><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="flag-icon flag-icon-fi"></span><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="">FI</span></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;">HELSINKI</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width: 4em;"><p-button _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" icon="pi pi-eye" ptooltip="View" tooltipposition="left" tabindex="0"><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" style=""><!----><span class="pi pi-eye ui-clickable ui-button-icon-left ng-star-inserted"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">ui-btn</span></button></p-button></td></tr><!----><!----><tr _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="ng-star-inserted"><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; vertical-align: top;"> EEA Branch</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10em; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/FI95081_VAR_GEN_MIG"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted">Folkefinans AS, Suomen sivuliike</span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/FI95081_VAR_GEN_MIG"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;">23220612</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;"><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="flag-icon flag-icon-fi"></span><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="">FI</span></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;">Helsinki</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width: 4em;"><p-button _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" icon="pi pi-eye" ptooltip="View" tooltipposition="left" tabindex="0"><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" style=""><!----><span class="pi pi-eye ui-clickable ui-button-icon-left ng-star-inserted"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">ui-btn</span></button></p-button></td></tr><!----><!----><tr _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="ng-star-inserted"><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; vertical-align: top;"> EEA Branch</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10em; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/RORBPJS40072"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted">BNP Paribas S.A. Paris Sucursala Bucuresti </span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/RORBPJS40072"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted">BNP Paribas S.A. Paris Sucursala Bucure?ti </span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;">RB-PJS-40-072 </td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;"><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="flag-icon flag-icon-ro"></span><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="">RO</span></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;">Bucuresti</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;">Bucure?ti</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width: 4em;"><p-button _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" icon="pi pi-eye" ptooltip="View" tooltipposition="left" tabindex="0"><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" style=""><!----><span class="pi pi-eye ui-clickable ui-button-icon-left ng-star-inserted"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">ui-btn</span></button></p-button></td></tr><!----><!----><tr _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="ng-star-inserted"><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; vertical-align: top;"> EEA Branch</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10em; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/FI00083_VAR_GEN_MIG"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted">Handelsbanken Finans Aktiebolag (publ), filialverksamheten i Finland</span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:15%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"><a _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" href="/register/cir/entityView/CRD_EEA_BRA/FI00083_VAR_GEN_MIG"><app-readonly-property _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" _nghost-mdy-c10=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-mdy-c10="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span><!----></app-readonly-property></a></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;">09221192</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:7%; vertical-align: top;"><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" class="flag-icon flag-icon-fi"></span><span _ngcontent-mdy-c7="">FI</span></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;">HELSINKI</td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width:10%; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align: top;"></td><td _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" style="width: 4em;"><p-button _ngcontent-mdy-c7="" icon="pi pi-eye" ptooltip="View" tooltipposition="left" tabindex="0"><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" style=""><!----><span class="pi pi-eye ui-clickable ui-button-icon-left ng-star-inserted"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">ui-btn</span></button></p-button></td></tr><!----><!----><!----><!----></tbody>
  ```