# Am I overloading the application server with too many requests?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, request, webdriver

Does it make a difference whether I load a website every two seconds or always reload it as soon as the website has reloaded?
So if I use python and selenium and the page or its subdirectories open every two seconds or as soon as the subdirectories are available? or the server may be overloaded.

```
for each in self.all:
    self.driver.get(each)
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'p')))
self.driver.get(each)
```

Comment: after a get method call, the driver will wait until a page load happens. (by default, though you can set PageLoadStrategy to "eager" or "none"...) Your 2nd method just adds a 1/2 second of time to poll... or 60 if it never finds a <p> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) is concerned

> - *Selenium automates browsers. That's it!*
> - *What you do with that power is entirely up to you.*

I don't see any issue in either of your code block involving:

- Iterating through `get()` requests.
- Inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for `presence_of_element_located()`

The only grey area is the [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) of `presence_of_element_located()`. If your usecase is to extract the *text* you must induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for **`visibility_of_element_located()`**

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Python + Selenium: Wait until element is fully loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905)
- [Can't find a way to scrape the resultant table after search using Selenium through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687781/cant-find-a-way-to-scrape-the-resultant-table-after-search-using-selenium-throu/57688853#57688853)

---

### A word of caution

Do not send automated queries to website which doesn't permits as per their *Terms of Service* else you may get blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes a difference. If you will do many requests in small amount of time, you can receive a `429` status code which means that you make too many requests. Also, you might receive captcha or trigger other security stuff.

Comment: Which of these methods is the safest?