# Python Web Scraping view contents of driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Python \ Selenium \ Chrome web drivers to perform web scraping in Visual Studio Code.

If I send a GET i.e.:

```
driver.get('https://my_test_website/customerRest/show/?id=123')
```

How do I actually view the contents of the reply?  If I run the URL in Chrome, I can view all the data in one huge body:

[image]

How do I view it in Python?  I ultimately want to insert it into a SQL table but the 1st step is to view via Python.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `driver.page_source`?

Comment: yes, I added a line print (driver.page_source) and that has worked

Answer (score 1):

To view the contents of the ***`<body>`*** tag you need to use the [**page_source**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) property.

```
page_source: Gets the source of the current page.
```

Usage:

```
driver.page_source
```

To print the contents within the console:

```
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: So the body contains data like this:

"auditCreatedBy":"admin","auditCreatedByDisplayName":"admin","auditUpdateDate":"2021-08-10T15:52:16Z","auditUpdatedBy":"CorePullData"

How could I retrieve something specific like the 'auditCreatedBy'?

Comment: @Michael that would depend on the type of element which contains the desired information. You can easily [scrape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57688853/7429447) it using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) and/or [BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47871704/7429447)

Comment: I've tried find element by ID and by name but it says it can't find them?

Comment: @Michael Shouldn't that be a seperate question all together? Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.